# Active Directory VBS Scripting, getting blank or no value for "cn" attribute

Tags: windows, vbscript, active-directory, wsh, windows-server-2016

I am writing a script to write the computer name ("CN") attribute of computer accounts in an OU of Active Directory into description field of the computer account but I am just getting blank or no value for CN attribute. I had attached the image of the code execution results (which shows blank value - i have four computers with the different computer name in the specified OU). Please help to check my code (I have hidden the Active Directory path which shows my company details) and advise me where I did I made a mistake. Thanks.
[image]

```
'Create connection to the Active Directory and to do Deep Search (throughout all child OUs)
On Error Resume Next
Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objCommand =   CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 3000
objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE 

'Select area (OU) where the operation that we wants to operates from
objCommand.CommandText ="SELECT AdsPath FROM 'LDAP://OU=Temp,OU=MAC,OU=Clients,OU=TEST Device Accounts,DC=TEST,DC=TEST,DC=TEST' WHERE objectCategory='computer'"

'Start Operation
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute

'Go to the first record (AD account) in the specified OU
objRecordSet.MoveFirst

'continue operation until the last record (AD Account) in the specified OU
Do Until objRecordSet.EOF

  'Declare few string variables to hold time values
  dim valuename
  string strmessage

  'set string named strUserPath to "AdsPath" value of a AD accounts' 
  properties, AdsPath = Active Directory Path
  strUserPath = objRecordSet.Fields("AdsPath").Value    

  'Get the AD object and assign it to objEntry
  set objEntry=GetObject(strUserPath)
  set valuename=objEntry.Get("cn")
  strmessage = "The computer name is :"&valuename
  wscript.Echo("The computer name is :"&valuename)
  objEntry.Description = strmessage
  objEntry.Setinfo
  objRecordSet.MoveNext

Loop
```

Comment: First mistake is “on error resume next”. Remove that first

Comment: Nowadays this would normally be done in power shell.